# display woocommerce categories with sub-categories, child, Thumbnails, name And other

Tags: woocommerce, categories

please check this image:
http://uupload.ir/files/4zsu_untitled123456.png

i need this category for my website.
ty

Comment: do you want to display on any other page or you want to display them in the shop page?

Comment: only display shop page.

Answer (score 0):

You’re asking if it is possible show both Categories and Sub-Categories on the shop page.

With the latest version of WooCommerce and the following settings in Customize >> WooCommerce >> Product Catalog, both parent categories and sub-categories will be displayed on the shop page:

http://cld.wthms.co/wfBb1q

If that is not the case – please try reverting to a default theme such as
Storefront https://woocommerce.com/storefront/ in order to check if the same is still happening.

You may also want to update WooCommerce to the latest version if it is outdated.

Alternatively, you can use a plugin such as WooCommerce Nested Category Layout https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-nested-category-layout/ although I’m not quite sure if that’s the layout you’re looking for.

I hope this helps!